# Newb: Update XAML Image Element During Runtime (WIndows Phone, .NET 4)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-7

Greetings all,

Thanks for reading and sharing any insights. I've created a new simple Windows Phone 7 application. I have two Image objects on the form I would like to update with various .png files. I have included the .png files into my project, and I believe I am building proper URi resources pointing to these files.

```
Uri myImage1URi = new Uri( strImage1, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute );
Uri myImage2URi = new Uri( strImage2, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute );

System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bi1 = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(myImage1URi);
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bi2 = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(myImage2URi);

image1.Source = bi1;
image1.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
image2.Source = bi2;
image2.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
```

This alone is not accomplishing what I want (to update the images to the two from the URi's).

I know there is something a bit off going on (IE: I am doing something dumb) in that all of the BitmapImage class descriptions mention that I have to do a .BeginInit() before I work with the BitmapImage object, and a .EndInit() call afterwards. These method calls don't work for me, so I know something is amiss....

Or maybe I am competely off base and I simply need a way to tell my main window to repaint itself? That thought has occurred to me as well.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The following will load an image that is in the appropriate path and is set as having a build action content.

```
myImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/filename.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

It assumes XAML on the page like:

```
<Image x:Name="myImg" />
```

This seems very similar to what you're doing. Simplify what you're doing ot get it working.
Does it work with just using one image?
Is the path in `strImageN` a valid path?
Do the image files have their build action set to Content?